# Is there a way to a run a Perl script within a Python program without installing Perl?

Tags: python, perl

I have a Perl script that can convert a binary file into a text file. Rather than rewriting the script in Python, I was wonder I could use this Perl script in my Python program, package it, and distribute it to computers that don't have Perl preinstalled into it.

Comment: See also [Is there a way to create an executable that runs both Python and Perl script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61486665/2173773)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl has ways to embed a perl interpreter into another program: mod_perl for Apache is such a thing. If you wanted to make a Python module that had an [embedded perl](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlembed.html) in it, you could probably make that happen.

It's probably less work to rewrite the functionality in Python though.