# Is there a way to create an executable that runs both Python and Perl script?

Tags: python, perl, executable

I'm building a Python program that also runs a Perl script from within. Is there a way to create an executable where the user of my program doesn't have to install Perl but has Python?

Comment: if you're calling a perl script from python, you have to have perl installed too.

Comment: @Snow oh man! okay. Thank you!

Comment: I did post a similar question but I didn't get any replies and instead got down votes so I deleted it. My apologizes.

Comment: @ikegami I went back to my deleted post and I didn't see any replies. Just to make sure, I looked at your "answers" history and I don't see my question there. I never got it :/

Comment: See also [pp](https://metacpan.org/pod/pp) for a way to create an executable of your Perl script that does not need to have `perl` installed

Comment: @HåkonHægland -- but if the code will be dependent on _additional module_ the final result is not guaranteed.

Comment: I guess what you're looking for is a perl interpreter written in python :::)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can use [`pp`](https://metacpan.org/pod/pp) to build an executable (that does not depend on the `perl` executable being installed).

I am using `perlbrew` with `perl` version 5.30 on Ubuntu 20.04.

- First install `pp`:

  ```
  cpanm PAR::Packer
  ```
- Create a test Perl script `hello.pl` (you may need to install `Path::Tiny` first):

  ```
  use feature qw(say);
  use strict;
  use warnings;
  use Path::Tiny;   # <-- NOTE: non-core module used
  say "Hello world! CWD = ", Path::Tiny->cwd;
  ```
- Pack it into an executable:

  ```
  pp -o hello hello.pl
  ```
- Test that the Perl script is independent of the `perl` executable, by erasing `PATH`:

  ```
  $ PATH= ./hello
  Hello world! CWD = /home/hakon/pp
  ```
- Create a test Python script, `t.py`:

  ```
  import os
  os.system("./hello")
  ```
- Run the Python script:

  ```
  $ python3 t.py
  Hello world! CWD = /home/hakon/pp
  ```

I also tested this with a Docker container where I transferred the compiled `hello` executable to the container and then ran `hello` from within the container.

#### Note:

If you transfer this executable to a machine with a different version of the core libraries (like `glibc`) than those used on the machine where the executable was built, the executable might fail to run on the target machine. See [this post](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0513/) for similar issue in Python and further discussion of this problem.